# Why are there two @interfaces for view controllers?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm learning some Objective-C, specifically iOS-related stuff. Whenever I generate a new `UIViewController`, or `UITableViewController`, etc, both the generated `.h` and `.m` files contain an `@interface`. The application will continue to compile if I delete the `@interface` from the `.m` file, also. What is the purpose of this `@interface` in the `.m` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it is a "class extension" (see [("Extensions" section of) the Objective-C intro docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2)). In practice, it has become common to use this as a "private" interface (it is only "visible" to the file in which it exists). Objective-C does not stop anyone else from calling these methods, but they won't "see" them (think of the .h file as your *public interface* and this anonymous category as your private interface).

It is handy for declaring `@property`s which you don't want to expose publicly.

Comment: It's actually a class extension. The distinction is important. Class extensions can add ivars to a class. Categories cannot.

Answer (score 4):

The @interface in the .m file is a class extension (a category with no name). It's now in the templates to let you put any declaration of internal methods or ivars you don't want to expose to other parts of the code.

With the advent of the modern Objective-C runtime and the progress of clang, a well written class should:

1) have only public methods in the header

2) have ivars and internal methods declared in the internal class extension